# Execute handlers when DOM ready as the inserted order

Tags: javascript, jquery, domready

I want to to execute the handlers I pass to the "ready" function in the order there were inserted.

I saw with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/xhjYh/) that the order is opposite- LIFO - like a stack.
Is there a way to execute in order of FIFO like a queue?

(obviously I can't just insert the handlers in opposite order...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will be executed in the order that they were inserted by default.

The reason why the fiddle you saw looks like a LIFO stack is because the `after` method adds the number directly after the element with id 'logs'. So 1 gets added first, so the text looks like:

```
Text:    The Log: 1
HTML:    <div id=log><label id="logs"> The Log: </label>1</div>
```

Then 2 gets added directly after logs:

```
Text:    The Log: 21
HTML:    <div id=log><label id="logs"> The Log: </label>21</div>
```

... continuing up to:

```
Text:    The Log: 4321
HTML:    <div id=log><label id="logs"> The Log: </label>4321</div>
```

[See here for your fiddle with alerts](http://jsfiddle.net/xhjYh/1/) so you can see the order more clearly.

Comment: ohh, so how do you explain the jsFiddle example I gave? http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/xhjYh/